# SizeOf an array as a field?

Tags: c#

```
class foo {
    int foo1;
    bar[] bars = new bar[64];
}

class bar {
    int bar1;
    int bar2;
}
```

I'm trying to read everything in the class `foo` (previously a struct, but can't instantiate array size in a struct). But this gives me an error saying that it can't calculate the size for `bar[]`, why is this, and how would I be able to do it?

```
foo bla = new foo();

foreach (var field in
    typeof(foo).GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance |
    BindingFlags.NonPublic |
    BindingFlags.Public)) {

    Console.WriteLine("({0}) {1} = {2} (size: {3})", field.FieldType, field.Name, field.GetValue(bla), Marshal.SizeOf(field.FieldType));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it has to do with the fact that your field is the array type - I cannot confirm this from documentation.

Maybe you should be sensitive to array types by checking `field.FieldType.IsArray` and then calculating the size manually. However, that isn't that straight-forward, as arrays can be multi-dimensional, or jagged (which means that analysis would be recursive).

Another option is to just stay away from attempting to discover size of array types.

On a related note, did you try your code on fields of generic type?

Comment: how would I check the array size manually? I've made so it can see what type of array it is and check that types size. But how do I get the array length from a field?